# How to add mouseover event in JavaScript to each list element created via on click event and show selected item with toggle effect?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dropdown menu using javaScript, however I have created a dropdown list using an array, but I am struggling to add the mouseOver event such that, when a user over a specific list item, the list item color changes to lightpink, bg color to black and shows a cursor pointer.

Finally , When I tried to click the button it always renders list item every time I click, I want to show a toggle effect, such that when a user click's button , show list items, then hide the same with the selected item.

I tried to add certain functionality but I do not know what went wrong.  Can anyone please correct me?

Any help or suggestions are helpful.

Thanks

Please see the code below which I have tried:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdownMain">
  <button id="dropdownBtn" class="dropdwonBtn"> Select Counrtry</button>
  <div id="dropdownList" class="dropdownList">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const countries = ["India", "Ireland", "USA", "UK"];

const dropdownBtn = document.getElementById("dropdownBtn");
const dropdownList = document.getElementById("dropdownList");

dropdownBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    const list = document.createElement("li");
    list.style.color = "#ff0000";
    list.style.listStyleType = "none";
    list.style.padding = "0.5rem";
    list.style.paddingLeft = "1.1rem";
    list.style.borderRadius = "5px";
    list.style.marginBottom = "0.2rem";
    list.style.marginTop = "0.2rem";

    // only should trigger when hover over list item
    list.addEventListener(
      "mouseover",
      (e) => {
        e.target.style.color = "black";
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "lightpink";
        e.style.cursor = "pointer";
        // reset the color after a short delay
        setTimeout(() => {
          e.target.style.color = "";
        }, 500);
      },
      false
    );

    list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i]));
    dropdownList.appendChild(list);
  }
});
```

Please see codepen demo here https://codepen.io/tapesh02/pen/ExRpgZb

Comment: Why not use CSS :hover? Seems like a lot of pain to use Javascript for this....

Comment: Hi @EgilHansen, the solution with CSS works well, but wanted to know if can we add the same using JavaScript. if so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help,

I did find the answer to the question as well with some different turns and twists,

Thanks for the support. Please see the code below:

**CODE**

```
const countries = ["India", "Ireland", "USA", "UK"];

const dropdownBtn = document.getElementById("dropdownBtn");
const dropdownList = document.getElementById("dropdownList");

const showList = () => {
    if (dropdownList.style.display === "none") {
        dropdownList.style.display = "block";
        countries.map((c) => {
            const list = document.createElement("li");
            list.className = "dropdownItem";

            list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                dropdownBtn.innerText = e.target.innerText;
                dropdownList.innerHTML = "";
            });

            list.append(c);
            dropdownList.append(list);
        });
    } else {
        dropdownList.style.display = "none";
        dropdownList.innerHTML = "";
    }
};

dropdownBtn.addEventListener("click", showList, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jay Swaminarayan!

Don't know why you want to achieve it using JS. Add this before the for loop

```
...
    dropdownList.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Notes

While I think it is pretty unanimous that CSS should be used for this sort of thing, I'm going to provide an example that does use JavaScript for the sake of sharing knowledge. I don't think using `mouseover` and `mouseout` for styling elements is practical in this case, but there is a chance this could be used for something else.

### Solution

All you really need to do is add 2 event listeners: `mouseover` and `mouseout`
In these event listeners you can add and remove whatever CSS you need. The more optimized way (*besides using `:hover` in CSS of course*) would be to use classes. This way you can add and remove a single class to change the style of each element.

Also, in regards to the list being added to the page multiple times when you click your dropdown button, this is because once you select a country, nothing happens. The list remains on the page, and your button of course is only set to add another set of `<li>` elements. So on each `<li>` element you can add an event listener that gets the country they clicked and clears the dropdown list. This way when they click to view the dropdown list again, it doesn't duplicate anything.

```js
const countries = ["India", "Ireland", "USA", "UK"],
dropdownBtn = document.getElementById("dropdownBtn"),
dropdownList = document.getElementById("dropdownList")

const showList = () => {
  if(dropdownList.innerText.length) {
    dropdownList.innerHTML = ""
    return
  }
  countries.forEach(c => {
    const list = document.createElement("li")
    list.className = "dropdownItem"

    list.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
      e.target.classList.add("active")
    })
    list.addEventListener("mouseout", e => {
      e.target.classList.remove("active")
    })
    list.addEventListener("click", e => {
      dropdownBtn.innerText = e.target.innerText
      dropdownList.innerHTML = ""
    })

    list.append(c)
    dropdownList.append(list)
  })
}

dropdownBtn.addEventListener("click", showList)
```

```css
.dropdownMain {
  width: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #ff0000,
    #ff0031,
    #ff0050,
    #f8006b,
    #eb1283
  );
  font: 0.9rem bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

button:hover {
  color: black;
  background: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

button:focus {
  color: #ff0000;
  background: inherit;
}

.dropdownList {
  width: inherit;
}

.dropdownItem {
  color: #F00;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: .5rem .5rem .5rem 1.1rem;
  margin: .2rem 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
  color: #000;
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownMain">
  <button id="dropdownBtn" class="dropdwonBtn">Select Country</button>
  <div id="dropdownList" class="dropdownList"></div>
</div>
```

A few other small changes were things like using `.forEach()` instead of a standard `for` loop. This is usually done when you have a standard array of items.

And you can actually use `.append()` with text to automatically append text to an element, rather than creating a text node.

And for the purposes of my example I take the selected country and place it in the dropdown button before clearing out the dropdown list. This just makes it feel more like a standard dropdown when selecting an option.

### EDIT

Here is a link to a [CopePen](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/dyKjLww) version of this that also incorporates some additional functionality to make this function more like a dropdown. Clicking anywhere outside of the dropdown will also cause the dropdown to close (as well as clicking an option or the top of the dropdown).

Comment: Hi @EssXTee Thanks for the solution and wonderful explanation, the solution is 90% correct, only the issue is why I see the duplicate array when I click the button, How can show toggle funtionality with this? any idea? 

Thanks for the help again

Comment: @TapeshPatel I didn't catch that initially, but I have updated my code snippet to fix duplicating the list. The easiest way I've learned to handle things like that is an ***exit/return statement***. Rather than a full `if/else` statement, you basically set an exit condition to check, and if true you exit the function, otherwise you can continue. Here we just check if there is already a list inside of the dropdown element.